# Is there any event for Create/edit/delete attributes Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, attributes, event-observer, magento2.4.2

When the attribute is created/edited/deleted I need to trigger a URL for that I need an event the is help on that scenario in Magento 2.4.2. I checked some URL's i didn't understand which is working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for **catalog_entity_attribute_save_before** and **catalog_entity_attribute_save_after**

Comment: How to identify the attribute is deleting or editing using this event

Comment: Check the origData with the data, not sure but you should be able to see if the attribute is getting deleted from the new data. For the Edit you should check column by column if there's any difference from the old and new data ($attribute->getOrigData('column'))